# Prisma's orm post doesnt work when doing post, see error below

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, prisma

Makinga simple prisma app with express and node, querying a mysql local database.
When doing await prisa.list.create(), it raises and error, see below.

script.js of the html page:

```
  addItemForm.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const itemName = itemNameInput.value.trim();
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ itemName: itemName }))
    if (itemName) {
      try {
        await fetch('/backend/api/add-person', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ itemName: itemName })
        });
        fetchData(); // Refresh the list after adding an item
        itemNameInput.value = ''; // Clear input field
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding item:', error);
      }
    }
  });
```

api.js:

```
  router.post('/add-person', async (req, res) => {
    const  itemName  = req.body.itemName;
    
    try {
      await prisma.list.create({
        data: {
          name: itemName
        }
      });
      res.redirect('/');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send('Error adding item to database');
    }
  });
```

Error:

```
   try {
   const  { name }  = req.body
   await prisma.list.create({
         data: {
       +   name: String
         }
       })
```

Argument `name` is missing.

prisma's model of the list:

```
model list {
  id   Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String @db.VarChar(255)
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PXQB.png

Comment: Please share the model of list table in your `schema.prisma`, And can you give me a screenshot for error?

Comment: If i write a string directly in the code data: { name: "MyString"} it works and is added to the table. But if i use the post of the script it doesnt.

Comment: Please post consistent code. The code you've supplied and the error don't match. `itemName  = req.body.itemName` vs `{ name }  = req.body`

Answer (score 0):

solved by using this express middleware:

app.use(express.json());